# StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory] | NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal

I am getting the following error, while trying to upgrade from angular 2 to angular 5

```
Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5548)
    at main (client.ts:24)
    at Object.bootloader (index.js:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (client.ts:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 031c386073943e31b8d3:19)
    at bootstrap 031c386073943e31b8d3:62
```

This is not a Angular CLI app so I have created a repo on git for minimal reproduction of the issue. Please refer the following [link](https://github.com/amit-kumar27/sample-app)

Refer README.md for build and serve the app.

Using webpack:3.11.0 For build this app.

Comment: There is a bug with the JITCompiler in angular 5 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20639#issuecomment-347149868